# How to get only custom fields from a list?

Tags: 2010, development, csom

I am working with the Client Side Object Model. In a console application I am retrieving all fields from a custom list. The problem is the Clientcontext fetches me a bunch of internal fields I do not want to be included. Also this causes some of the fields to appear more than once.

```
string siteURL = "http:XYZ";
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
Web oWebSite = context.Web;
context.Load(oWebSite);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//Get the list by title
List produktKatalogListe = spLists.GetByTitle("Produktkatalog");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";
ListItemCollection listItems = produktKatalogListe.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(produktKatalogListe);
context.Load(listItems);
context.Load(produktKatalogListe.Fields);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(Field field in produktKatalogListe.Fields)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}",field.Title,field.InternalName,field.Hidden,field.CanBeDeleted,field.FieldTypeKind);
}
```

Is there a way to print only custom fields? This would mean omitting fields like `internalID`, `GUID`...

I tried the following:

```
if(!field.Hidden)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}",field.Title,field.InternalName,field.Hidden,field.CanBeDeleted,field.FieldTypeKind);
}
```

Unfortunately this not only does not solve the issue but is also not a very good solution for the case I do want to display custom but hidden fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach seems to solve the issue. Instead for checking if the field is not `Hidden` I checked whether it is not `FromBaseType`.

```
if(!field.FromBaseType)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}",field.Title,field.InternalName,field.Hidden,field.CanBeDeleted,field.FieldTypeKind);
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. in JSOM: `oField.get_fromBaseType()`

Answer (score 8):

In SSOM [SPField.SourceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.sourceid.aspx) property allows to determine

> either the namespace that defines a built-in field or, if it a **custom**
>   **field**, the GUID that identifies the list or Web site where it was
>   created.

In CSOM `SourceId` property is not exposed for [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.ASPX) object, but it could be extracted from [SchemaXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.schemaxml%28v=office.15%29.aspx) as demonstrated below:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> ParseSchemaXml(string schemaXml)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(schemaXml);
        var attributes = xdoc.Descendants("Field").Attributes();
        foreach (var attr in attributes)
        {
          if(!properties.ContainsKey(attr.Name.LocalName))
              properties.Add(attr.Name.LocalName,attr.Value);
        }
        return properties;
    }


    //Usage
    var properties = ParseSchemaXml(field.SchemaXml);
    var sourceId = properties["SourceID"];
```

The below example demonstrates how to retrieve and print custom fields for a List:

```
    public static void PrintCustomFields(string url, string listTitle)
    {
        const string fieldBuiltInNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3";
        using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            //context.Credentials = credentials;
            var web = context.Web;
            var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            web.Context.Load(list, l => l.Fields);
            web.Context.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (var field in list.Fields)
            {
                var properties = ParseSchemaXml(field.SchemaXml);
                if (properties["SourceID"] != fieldBuiltInNS)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}",field.InternalName);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```